# Resources Sharing Policy

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I'm afraid to sound uncouth, but what is our policy as for sharing resources, namely copyrighted books in PDF? How much of a book is it OK to share? Can I share screenshots or just text? 
As for me, I'd share everything I have including complete books. Especially Soviet books, since the USSR denied all the copyright. Or am I missing something and there's an article in the SE rules I overlooked?

Comment: See discussion on Meta.SE: [Are links to possibly illegally hosted copyrighted material allowed or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171488/256282)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I haven't seen any other responses yet:

My rule of thumb is that approximately one page of not-freely-available text is fine. Clearly, *some* amount of quotation is necessary for educational purposes, and distributing entire copyrighted books for free would cause legal problems for the site. And my understanding (though I am very much not a lawyer) is that there's no hard limit defined in the law, but a page is usually considered acceptable.

At this point, the moderators haven't been deleting questions or answers that have excessive quotations, and we haven't run into any legal issues yet; if there's a network-wide rule on this, I don't know it. But I'm not opposed to coming up with a firmer policy on this, just in case.

(Of course, this is specifically for resources that are not freely available. If a work is open-access, public domain, available in a preprint database, or otherwise accessible, I see no reason to forbid putting it here.)